# UI Animation Blocks Touches

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to animate some text in my `UIScrollview`. But I suspect that this code blocks my touch events.

I read that I need to set animation options and use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to enable touches. But I could not figured our to use that option without using `AnimateWithDuration` block. How can I use `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` with the following code block.

```
-(void) startAnimation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self cache:YES];   
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =  self.contentSize.width/kPixelsPerSecond;
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width - self.frame.size.width, 0);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use animation block and set the option ? Is there a reason or you didn't managed to set it right ?

Comment: I could not convert this code to animatewithduration version. That's why :) I am not an expert :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> How can I use UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction with the
>   following code block.

Answer: You can't. The beginAnimations/commitAnimations technique is discouraged as of iOS 4. That's 3 major releases ago. Apple has not updated those old-style animations since iOS 4, and will likely deprecate them at some point.

You should use the newer `animateWithDuration:animations:` style animation code. It can do everything that the older beginAnimations/commitAnimations code can, and much more (like using the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction setting, just as an example.

(Note that you can't handle touches on a view that is moving across the screen by simply using the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option. You have to write special code that receives the touches in the parent view and then does hit testing on the presentationLayer of the view that's being animated. That does not appear to be relevant to what you're trying to do, but it's still worth noting.)

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately i could not write the same one with animateWithDuration.

Comment: The older beginAnimations/commitAnimations calls do not support that option. So edit your post to show your failed code and ask for help getting it to work. (Transition animations are different with the newer calls, but most of the transitions are supported)

Comment: Thank you. I replaced my existing code with animateWithDuration:animations.

Comment: So you're up and running now?